# authorize with a parent resource in Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I have a `Campaign` model which has many `Applicants`. I'm currently nesting Applicants within Campaigns. I'm trying to authorize a user to `applicants#index` based on if they are the owner of the campaign.

```
  resources :campaigns do
    ..
    resources :applicants do
      ..
    end
  end
```

What's the best way to secure the `applicants#index` action in Pundit? Ideally I would like to pass the `@Campaign` to authorize.

```
class ApplicantsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @applicants = Applicant.where(campaign: @campaign)

        authorize @campaign
        respond_with(@applicants)
    end
```

But this results in Pundit looking for `campaign_policy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably use the `show?` method on the `CampaignPolicy`

```
authorize @campaign, :show?
```

where `show?` *(call it whatever you want...`manage?`, etc...)* would be

```
def show?
  record.user_id = user.id
end
```

Just because the resource being displayed is a list of applicants doesn't mean you need to authorize against them directly. If your logic requires authorizing the owner of the campaign, do that.

Finally, if this is some wide-spread, common thing in your application, you might consider creating some value object to wrap your current user and campaign in.

```
class CurrentState < Struct.new(:user, :campaign); end
```

and then override the `pundit_user` method.

```
def pundit_user
  CurrentState.new(current_user, Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
end
```

See [Additional Context](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#additional-context) in the Pundit docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see it's defaulting to show?, How can I override this? Otherwise the same rule would apply to campaigns/11

Comment: What's defaulting to `show?` In the first line of code provided, the 2nd argument, `:show?` overrides the default *(which would be `:index?`)*. Change that symbol to specify a different method on your `CampaignPolicy`.

Comment: One thing I would like to mention. I feel like when I authorize an action, it should be looking for the policy related to that action, rather than the policy relating to the passed object. I get why it's not, but this is my thoughts.